# micromax a55 is not being connected with adb

Tags: android, adb

i have micromax a55 bling2 with android froyo. I have installed driver of usb adb interface. But still i could not see the device in the adb devices list. Hope someone could help me get out of this.

Comment: http://www.downloadatoz.com/howto/how-to-set-up-install-android-adb-usb-driver,30261.html#d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I installed [adb wireless](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=siir.es.adbWireless) on Micromax A55 and was successfully able to debug through my wifi network.

note : for using this application you need your phone to be rooted. I used [Z4-root.1.3.0.apk](http://www.filecrop.com/Z4-root.1.3.0.apk.html)

Answer (score 4):

If you are running Ubuntu/Linux Just Key in

```
"lsusb -v "
```

and press enter.
It will bring out details of all USB devices.
Check for a field called "idVendor" in the results and find your device.
Eg: My Motorola Defy[vendor id = 22b8] gives,

" idVendor           0x22b8 Motorola PCS"
Add the above vendor id to a51-rules.Install proper drivers.
Follow this,
http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html

Comment: I have no idea how it happened. May be your Micromax is using a Rom that is ported From an HTC Rom. But chances are less that such a thing happens

Comment: @ByzantineFailure my micromax also!

Comment: Hey try editing the rules-51 file if you are using Ubuntu for dev. The device defaults to HTC.

Answer (score 1):

I am reproducing the rules-51 file here, it works for me for my Micromax phone:

```
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="0bb4", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev" 
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="0502", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev" 
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="0b05", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev" 
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="413c", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev" 
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="0489", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev" 
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="04c5", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev" 
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="04c5", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev" 
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="091e", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev" 
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="18d1", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev" 
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="201E", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev" 
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="109b", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev" 
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="12d1", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev" 
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="24e3", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev" 
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="2116", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev" 
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="0482", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev" 
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="17ef", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev" 
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="1004", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev" 
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="22b8", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev" 
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="0e8d", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev" 
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="0409", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev" 
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="2080", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev" 
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="0955", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev" 
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="2257", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev" 
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="10a9", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev" 
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="1d4d", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev" 
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="0471", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev" 
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="04da", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev" 
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="05c6", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev" 
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="1f53", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev" 
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="04e8", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev" 
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="04dd", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev" 
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="054c", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev" 
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="0fce", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev" 
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="2340", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev" 
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="0930", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev" 
SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ATTR{idVendor}=="19d2", MODE="0666", GROUP="plugdev"
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, finally my android one is connected to adb

Answer (score 0):

I just googled and found this,
[Drivers for A55](http://micromaxinfo.com/products/A55/)

The whole GUI OR say PC suite which people use to sync their phone data is "not Must have thing" to connect your phone.

You need to have only drivers which can set up your machine so that adb can simply detect your phone.

Answer (score 0):

Start USB debugging(in settings>applications>developer options) on device first.

And still there is problem, try following link. http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html

It helped me to detect my Micromax Canvas Hd.

I tied Motorola's "22b8" value and it worked for Micromax. Also on friends PC the idea worked. We done it for Ubuntu 32 and 64 bi