# Retrieving video uri at particular row and column from sqllite database

Tags: android, sqlite

This is project for video recorder.The only problem I am having is retrieving stored uri of video from sqllite.The project works fine if I don't call retrieveVid() method but it crashes out when retrieveVid() method is called.Here I am trying to retrieve the uri stored at column 1 and row 2 of sqllite database.Inside checkEvents() method I have commented the other codes which I have tried . Problem might be in checkEvents() or getEvents() method or retrieveVid() method.Since I am running the project on mobile as camera doesn't work on my emulator so i don't have logcat.I am not posting SecondActvity.java as it is not related to database or my problem.

logcat

```
06-25 21:36:24.501: E/CursorWindow(23206): Failed to read row 2, column 1 from a CursorWindow which has 123 rows, 1 columns.
06-25 21:36:24.504: D/AndroidRuntime(23206): Shutting down VM
06-25 21:36:24.504: W/dalvikvm(23206): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40e89908)
06-25 21:36:24.514: E/AndroidRuntime(23206): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-25 21:36:24.514: E/AndroidRuntime(23206): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=200, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=file:///storage/sdcard0/Pictures/Hello Camera/VID_20140625_213611.mp4 }} to activity {com.example.Assignment/com.example.Assignment.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 2, col 1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
06-25 21:36:24.514: E/AndroidRuntime(23206):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3302)
06-25 21:36:24.514: E/AndroidRuntime(23206):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3345)
06-25 21:36:24.514: E/AndroidRuntime(23206):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:149)
06-25 21:36:24.514: E/AndroidRuntime(23206):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1348)
06-25 21:36:24.514: E/AndroidRuntime(23206):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-25 21:36:24.514: E/AndroidRuntime(23206):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
06-25 21:36:24.514: E/AndroidRuntime(23206):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5086)
06-25 21:36:24.514: E/AndroidRuntime(23206):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-25 21:36:24.514: E/AndroidRuntime(23206):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-25 21:36:24.514: E/AndroidRuntime(23206):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:821)
06-25 21:36:24.514: E/AndroidRuntime(23206):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:584)
06-25 21:36:24.514: E/AndroidRuntime(23206):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-25 21:36:24.514: E/AndroidRuntime(23206): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Couldn't read row 2, col 1 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it.
06-25 21:36:24.514: E/AndroidRuntime(23206):    at android.database.CursorWindow.nativeGetString(Native Method)
06-25 21:36:24.514: E/AndroidRuntime(23206):    at android.database.CursorWindow.getString(CursorWindow.java:434)
06-25 21:36:24.514: E/AndroidRuntime(23206):    at android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getString(AbstractWindowedCursor.java:51)
06-25 21:36:24.514: E/AndroidRuntime(23206):    at com.example.Assignment.MainActivity.checkEvents(MainActivity.java:367)
06-25 21:36:24.514: E/AndroidRuntime(23206):    at com.example.Assignment.MainActivity.retrieveVid(MainActivity.java:374)
06-25 21:36:24.514: E/AndroidRuntime(23206):    at com.example.Assignment.MainActivity.onActivityResult(MainActivity.java:321)
06-25 21:36:24.514: E/AndroidRuntime(23206):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5204)
06-25 21:36:24.514: E/AndroidRuntime(23206):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3298)
06-25 21:36:24.514: E/AndroidRuntime(23206):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: Please enable usb debugging on the phone and check the logcat then. http://www.phonearena.com/news/How-to-enable-USB-debugging-on-Android_id53909

Comment: @tkneel I have enabled usb debugging and connected my device to computer..now how can i see logcat?

Comment: If you device doesn't show up in your IDE as connected device, look here: http://developer.android.com/tools/device.html , otherwise, just use the logcat as you do with the emulator.

Comment: @tknell my phone is of Micromax and no OEM driver listed for tht

Comment: Do you use windows or linux? For windows, there should be a driver available http://www.micromaxinfo.com/downloads.aspx , for linux try this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14113087/2857385

Comment: @tknell logcat posted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Column indexing starts at 0. Your table has only 1 column. You don't specify a projection so all columns are returned in the cursor. Attempting to retrieve the value at column index 1 causes the exception.

To fix it, change `getString(1)` to `getString(0)`.

Answer (score 1):

First off, you try to read the second row of your cursor without checking if it is there. Also, like @laalto said, the columns on the cursor are zero-based, so with ´getString(1)´ you won't get anything, because the table has only one column.

I'd recommend you to get the String like this, this will be save, even if you add further rows to your Table:

```
if(cursor.moveToPosition(2)){
    a = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(sql.COLUMN_VID)); 
    // add a constant (COLUMN_VID) to your sql class which defines the row name and also use this constant in your table creation
}
```